# From array of arrays to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of array (`map`) like this one:

```
var map = [
    ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'],
    ['car', 'pen', 'table', 'cup', 'pillow'],
    ['5', '6', '1', '2', '10'],
    ['15', '2', '2', '3', '20'],
    ['50', '60', '13', '1', '1']
];
```

I want convert this array in this arrray of objects:

```
var jsons = [
    {color: 'red', obj: 'car', value: '5'}, 
    {color: 'red', obj: 'pen', value: '6'}, 
    {color: 'red', obj: 'table', value: '1'}, 
    {color: 'red', obj: 'cup', value: '2'}, 
    {color: 'red', obj: 'pillow', value: '10'}, 
    {color: 'blue', obj: 'car', value: '15'}, 
    {color: 'blue', obj: 'pen', value: '2'}, 
    {color: 'blue', obj: 'table', value: '2'}, 
    {color: 'blue', obj: 'cup', value: '3'}, 
    {color: 'blue', obj: 'pillow', value: '20'},
    {color: 'yellow', obj: 'car', value: '50'}, 
    {color: 'yellow', obj: 'pen', value: '60'}, 
    {color: 'yellow', obj: 'table', value: '13'}, 
    {color: 'yellow', obj: 'cup', value: '1'}, 
    {color: 'yellow', obj: 'pillow', value: '1'}
];
```

I tried this code:

```
var thisJson = [];
var colors = map.shift(); 
var objs = map.shift();  

thisJson = map.reduce(function(result, v, i) {
    v.forEach(function(o, k) {
        result.push({color: colors[k], obj: objs[i], value: o});
    });
    return result;
}, jsons);
```

But it doesn't work because I get:

```
[
    {color: 'red', obj: 'car', value: '5'}, 
    {color: 'blue', obj: 'pen', value: '6'}, 
    {color: 'yellow', obj: 'table', value: '1'}, 
    ...
]
```

How can I solve?

---

I can see these data structures as tables.
On the left is the table that I would like, on the right the one I get.

[image]

It is clear that they are different.

Comment: JSON is `String`, not an `Object`. And btw, the result you claim to get and the expected result are identical.

Comment: @connexo The result I get is not the same I want.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's wrong with the result you get? The logic isn't very clear.

Comment: @connexo I edited my main message, I hope now it's more clear.

Comment: @JJJ I edited my main message, I hope now it's more clear.

Comment: @connexo Maybe it's me who does not understand what you mean. In any case they are not the same because `{color: 'blue', obj: 'pen', value: '6'}` is different from `{color: 'blue', obj: 'pen', value: '2'}`.

Comment: @beth  `Maybe it's me`  Please remember that on SO there are lots of questions, and it really helps if you explain the problem too, posting the 2 arrays for us to compare is great, but it would have been way better if you also said something like  `Notice how on the second array the color props go red, blue, yellow instead of red, red, red`.   Otherwise SO users have to play spot the difference.  And with SO having so many questions it's a game most of us have no time to play.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using loops:

```js
var map = [
    ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'],
    ['car', 'pen', 'table', 'cup', 'pillow'],
    ['5', '6', '1', '2', '10'],
    ['15', '2', '2', '3', '20'],
    ['50', '60', '13', '1', '1']
];
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < map[0].length; i++){
    var color = map[0][i];
    for(var j = 0; j < map[1].length; j++){
       result.push({color:color, obj: map[1][j], value: map[i+2][j]});
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

The important part here is how the value is set `value: map[i+2][j]`. The value is set using the index in the colours array.

Also, this will only work correctly if the number of elements of the values array is the same as the one for the objects array and there are as many values array as there are elements in the colours array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shift` to remove the first element of the array and store it on a variable.

And you can use `map` and `reduce` for form the desired output.

Here is a snippet.

```js
let map = [
  ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'],
  ['car', 'pen', 'table', 'cup', 'pillow'],
  ['5', '6', '1', '2', '10'],
  ['15', '2', '2', '3', '20'],
  ['50', '60', '13', '1', '1']
];

let color = map.shift();  //Remove the first element on the array and store on a variable
let object = map.shift(); //Remove the first element on the array and store on a variable

//Map the rest
let jsons = map.map((v, i) => {
  return v.map((o, k) => {return {color: color[i],obj: object[k],value: o};});
}).reduce((c, v) => c.concat(v), []);

console.log(jsons);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const result = [];

const keys = ["color", "obj", "value"];

 for(const [key, values] of map.entries())
    for(const [pos, value] of values.entries())
       (result[pos] || (result[pos] = {}))[keys[key]] = value;
```